# AJAX Fave Button Not Working Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to allow users to favorite posts and then it show them sort of of interaction through AJAX, but it's not working.

The error I'm getting in the console is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `post_item' for #<#<Class:0x007fecb2a3d5f8>:0x007fecb2a357e0>):
```

The button is being rendered through a partial:

```
<%= render "shared/fave_form", post_item: post_item %>
```

Here's the code for the button (shared/_fave_form.html.erb):

```
<% if current_user.voted_on?(Post.find(post_item)) %>
     <%= link_to "unlike", vote_against_post_path(post_item.id), :remote => true, :method => :post, :class => "btn") %>
<% else %>
     <%= link_to "like", vote_up_post_path(post_item.id), :remote => true, :method => :post, :class => "btn") %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the toggle.js.erb file:

```
 $("#fave").html("<%= escape_javascript render('fave_form') %>");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you render the partial using `toggle.js.erb` it is not getting `locals` value `post_item`, you have to provide it in also.So, your js code should be something like following

```
$("#fave").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>"fave_form", locals: {post_item: post_item}).html_safe %>);
```

I guess you are using some ajax call and then your `toggle.js.erb` so in your `toggle` action you must specify value to `post_item`, lets make it instance variable `@post_item` so that we can use it in `toggle.js.erb`.

```
$("#fave").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>"fave_form", locals: {post_item: @post_item}).html_safe %>);
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error in the console? I used your code and it produced the same thing.

Comment: For some reason, it's still not working? Maybe it's something in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The partial is using a local variable, so pass `post_item` as a local:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/fave_form", :locals => {post_item: post_item} %>
```

Comment: Still getting the same thing.